# Is printf sensitive to the order of arguments?

Tags: c++, printf, zero

I want to print a simple line using **printf** in **c++**

```
    int t0 = time(NULL);
    int outIndx = 99736;
    printf ("time using recurision = %d secs, the result is = %d\n",(time(NULL) - t0), outIndx);
```

In this case the output of printf is :

time using recurision = 0 secs, the result is = 0

But when reversing the order of **outIndx** and **(time(NULL) - t0)**:

```
printf ("time using recurision = %d secs, the result is = %d\n", outIndx,(time(NULL) - t0));
```

the output of printf is printed correctly:

time using recurision = 99736 secs, the result is = 0

Why does this happen?.

Comment: You do know that the normal resolution for `time` is in seconds? So if the time you measure took less than a second (even if it's 0.99 seconds) then the result will still be zero.

Comment: **Of course** it's sensitive to the order of arguments, and the *man* page says so. Otherwise it would be completely useless.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, meaning that if i wanna catch time less than a sec, i have to make the type `float`?. I tried this and didn't work.

Comment: @Misaki No, you have to use some other functions that gives you higher resolution, for example [`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) or [`clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) (but note that  in Windows using the Visual Studio compiler [the `clock` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) behaves in a nonstandard way, it can still be used though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` returns a `time_t` which does not have to be the same size as an `int`. In that case `%d` is not the correct format for the output.

Comment: Ok, but why this affects the printing of `outIndx` ?

Comment: Once you have an incorrect format, the result is technically undefined.  In practice, a larger element will cause the next element to be in a place where `printf` doesn't find it.

Comment: @Misaki Because by passing an argument that doesn't match the format specifier, you get *undefined behaviour* (UB). Strange behaviour like what you observe is usually an indication of UB in your code.

Comment: What can i use to print time in this case?, i tried `%lld`for the time and it worked. I don't understand why though :D

Comment: @Misaki - It's a bit complicated and depends on your system. If you believe that `time_t` fits in an `int` on your system, you can do `int t1 = time(NULL) - t0;` and print `t1`.

Answer (score 1):

Original question: "Is printf sensitive to the order of arguments?"

The order in which the parameters to a function is not defined in the standard, and is determined by the calling convention used by the compiler. Let's suppose you are using the cdecl calling convention (which many C compilers use for x86 architecture) in which arguments in a function get evaluated from **right to left.**

Let's take an example

```
int i=5;
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d",i++,i--,++i,--i,i);
Output :45545
```

It is because arguments are evaluated from right to left.

However, in your example, you tried to print time which id of type "time_t" which is as below :

```
typedef __time_t time_t;
```

The time_t datatype is a data type in the ISO C library defined for storing system time values. Such values are returned from the standard time() library function. This type is a typedef defined in the standard header. ISO C defines time_t as an arithmetic type, but does not specify any particular type, range, resolution, or encoding for it. Also unspecified are the meanings of arithmetic operations applied to time values.

It depends on the underlying architecture whether it is implemented in terms of integer or not.  As far as your example is concerned, I believe it is not implemented as "unsigned int " at least (int t0), so result is implementation-defined.

Comment: You're mixing up several different topics here, only one of which is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### A C Solution

Generally, the way to display the value of a [`time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) is to break down its components to a [`struct tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) using [`gmtime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime) or [`localtime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) and display those or convert them as desired with [`strftime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime), or [`ctime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/ctime) to go directly from `time_t` to a string showing local time.

If you want to see the raw value for some purpose, the C standard specifies that `time_t` is real, which means it is integer or floating-point (C 2011 (N1570) 6.2.5 17). Therefore, you should use [`difftime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime) which convert a time difference to a double:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

void process()
{
    static unsigned dummy = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 1000000000 ; ++i)
    {
        dummy += (dummy + i) / (dummy * i + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const time_t t0 = time(NULL);
    process(); // let say it can take up to a few hours
    const time_t t_end = time(NULL);

    struct tm breakdown_time = { 0 };
    breakdown_time.tm_sec = difftime(t_end, t0);
    (void) mktime(&breakdown_time);
    printf("duration: %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n", breakdown_time.tm_hour, breakdown_time.tm_min, breakdown_time.tm_sec);
    // Output: "duration: 00:00:08"
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8ba5584777b5693)

#### A C++ Solution

But aren't you working with C++? [`std::clock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) provide a way to compute CPU time duration (time spent by the CPU, not counting the time it spent on other threads for instance):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void process()
{
    static unsigned dummy = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 1000000000 ; ++i)
    {
        dummy += (dummy + i) / (dummy * i + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    const std::clock_t t0 = std::clock();
    process(); // business code that take time to run
    const std::clock_t t_end = std::clock();
    const double duration = static_cast<double>(t_end - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "duration: " << std::setprecision(3) << duration << " s" << std::endl;
    // Output: "duration: 8.92 s"
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adacc42b82730df2)

#### A C++14 Solution

I've stumbled on an elegant, versatile way to compute real duration, it's in C++14 and use all the advanced tools in [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

void process()
{
    static unsigned dummy = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 100000000 ; ++i)
    {
        dummy += (dummy + i) / (dummy * i + 1);
    }
}

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F&& func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT> 
                            (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "duration: " << measure<>::execution(process) << " ms" << std::endl;
    // Output: "duration: 707 ms"
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1db156c88e65eccf)

Comment: What do you think about using `GetTickCount()`?

Comment: @Misaki Windows-only function ;)

Answer (score 1):

all the arguments passed to printf (variable argument function) are pushed to stack while calling. printf routine pops the arguments based on `%` identifier provided in its first argument serially. depending on machine and compiler order of argument on the stack (top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top) may vary.

in your case, when you pass `(time(NULL) - t0)` first, since it is of type time_t and its size is not same as printf interprets by seeing `%d`. it creates issue.

**now why it works when you pass `(time(NULL) - t0`) as second argument:**

again same logic, assume timt_t in your case is of 8 bytes where as int is of 4 bytes. for every `%d` printf will consume 4 bytes from argument stack. so when you print `outIdx(int)` first, printf gets correct 4 bytes from stack corresponding to outIdx. when printf see second `%d`, it will use 4 next bytes which is part of the 8 bytes of time_t object. And depending on value of time_t, endianness of the system, print will print 4 bytes (out of 8) from stack assuming it as int.

when print is provided with wrong `%` identifier, you may endup with messing up with its stack arrangement and may get improper or undefined behaviour.